input sobre una secuencia de una letras y 9 numeros
Supongamos que queremos introducir por teclado una secuencia formada por una letra y 9 números separados por un espacio, por ejemplo:
C 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Si lo hiciéramos en C++ haríamos:
char letra;
int array[9];

std::cin >> letra:

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    std::cin >> array[i]

Sin embargo en Python parece algo más elaborado, probablemente por que las variables no tienen un tipo predefinido, si no que se adaptan al valor que reciben, o quizá por que no tengo los conocimientos suficientes. En este caso lo haría de la siguiente forma:
a = input()         # 'a' tomo como valor un string: 'C 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'
b = a.split(" ")    # conversión de string a list: ['C' '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9']
c = b.pop(0)        # extraemos el primer carácter: 'C' y lo borramos del list
d = [int(x) for x in b]  # convertimos el list de str a int

¿Hay alguna forma más directa de realizar esto en Python?
Gracias.

Puedes usar la notación de corte: d=input[1::2]

Disculpa pero no entiendo como funciona el input con la notación de corte, lo he intentado probar y me da error.

Obviamente, algo has hecho mal, porque aquí funciona perfectamente. De todas formas, puedes revisar la documentación oficial.

La rebanada, en el ejemplo que pones, no se aplica sobre el input, sino sobre la variable que lo recibe, en este caso la 'd', entendí que el input en si, podía soportar una rebanada y descartar datos de entrada.

Eso no se puede hacer en ningún lenguaje, ni en C++. No puedes descartar nada sin haberlo leído antes.

El código que tienes en C++ correspondiente a Python sería:
array = []
letra = input()
for _ in range(9):
    array.append(int(input()))

Para hacerlo todo con un solo input es practicamente como lo describes:
a = input()
b = a.split(' ')
c = b[0] # <- Esto no borra el elemento
d = [int(x) for x in b[1:]]

Si quieres descartar cualquier entrada no numérica, en el momento de la captura, podrías filtrarla:
array = []
print("Presione otra vez ENTER para terminar")
while(True):
    data = input('Entra un numero: ')
    if not data:
        break
    if data.isnumeric():
        array.append(int(data))
    else:
        print('Descartando:', data)

print(array)


Python no tiene esa característica. input() equivale a cin.getline() en C++.
Tendrás que crear tu propia implementación de lo que buscas. Podrías leer la entrada con input() o directamente desde sys.stdin y utilizar un algoritmo o expresiones regulares. Esta forma te daría bastante flexibilidad.
Otra cosa que se me ocurre es: toma la funcionalidad de C++ y crea una librería para poder usarla en Python. Para eso puedes usar pybind11.
Sería bastante simple hacerlo:
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

template<typename T>
T leer(){
    T n;
    cin >> n;
    return T;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(libreria, m) {
    m.def("leerInt", &leer<int>);
    m.def("leerFloat", &leer<float>);
    m.def("leerDouble", &leer<double>);
    m.def("leerString", &leer<string>);
}

Habría que exponer algunas funciones como good y clear para saber si ocurrió algún error en la lectura y poder continuar.
Entonces desde Python importas la librería y llamas esas funciones:
import libreria

numero = libreria.leerInt()
print(type(numero)) # Debería imprimir el tipo int 


El código de Python que puse, sin utilizar ninguna librería, ¿es optimizable o estaría correcto?

@Torkan no está mal, simplemente es otra forma de hacerlo. La diferencia es que con input trabajas con líneas y la entrada con formato de cin trabaja con caracteres. Yo creo que así está bien porque lo típico es que el usuario ingrese una línea
